# Hiding the Window Menu when app is full screen on Windows?

Tags: javascript, electron

I have an Electron app running on OSX and Windows. When the Windows version is full screen it still shows a menu bar and I would like it not to. Basically I want what happens on OSX: when the app is "full screen" no menu bar or window 'chrome' should appear.

I've tried `setAutoHideMenuBar` during my window set up but that made no difference. Am I using it wrong or misunderstanding what it is supposted to do?

I've seen some QAs suggestin `setMenu(null)` but won't that blow out the menu entirely? I do want the menu when in window mode or (on Windows) when the Alt key is pressed.

---

```
   mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,
        resizable: true,
        backgroundColor: '#222',
        center: true,
        setAutoHideMenuBar: true
    });
```

From the [docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetautohidemenubarhide):

> win.setAutoHideMenuBar(hide)
>
> ```
> hide Boolean
> ```
>
> Sets whether the window menu bar should hide itself automatically.
>   Once set the menu bar will only show when users press the single Alt
>   key.
>
> If the menu bar is already visible, calling setAutoHideMenuBar(true)
>   won’t hide it immediately.

From the [docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetmenubarvisibilityvisible-windows-linux)

> win.setMenuBarVisibility(visible) Windows Linux
>
> ```
> visible Boolean
> ```
>
> Sets whether the menu bar should be visible. If the menu bar is
>   auto-hide, users can still bring up the menu bar by pressing the
>   single Alt key.

From the [docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/browser-window/#winsetmenumenu-linux-windows)

> win.setMenu(menu) Linux Windows
>
> ```
> menu Menu
> ```
>
> Sets the menu as the window’s menu bar, setting it to null will remove
>   the menu bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An error on my part and a "go figure"

1. I was misusing the `setAutoHideMenuBar` command, trying to use it as an option when creating the window. The correct option syntax is `autoHideMenuBar: true`.

---

```
app.on('ready', function () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        show: false,
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,
        resizable: true,
        backgroundColor: '#222',
        center: true,
        autoHideMenuBar: true
    });
```

---

2. To handle toggling fullscreen, in setting up my menu I used the shortcut

   `role: 'togglefullscreen'`

While this works and includes the keyboard accelerators, the menu bar always appears and the `autoHideMenuBar`setting is apparently ignored. I don't understand why. So instead of the shortcut, I use this and the menu bar hides correctly.

```
            {
                label: 'Toggle Full Screen',
                click: () => { toggleFullscreen();},
                accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+f'
            }
```

---

```
function toggleFullscreen() {
    if (mainWindow.isFullScreen()) {
        mainWindow.setFullScreen(false);
    } else {
        mainWindow.setFullScreen(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setFullScreen` method.

```
function (item, focusedWindow) {
    if (focusedWindow) {
        focusedWindow.setFullScreen(!focusedWindow.isFullScreen())
    }
}
```